# Jquery mobile select menu overlays on extreme right

Tags: jquery-mobile, position, overlay, select-menu

I am using jquery mobile select menu with data-native-menu as false. The issue is if i click select menu, overlay popups on extreme right, instead of above the select menu control. i fixed my page max-width as 400px. Jquery mobile calculating the overlay position based on screen size,hence if i reduced the screen size overlay popup above the select menu control. But how can i make the select menu to overlay within my page size in maximized mode of screen?

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;">
<div data-role="page" style="width:400px">

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="select-choice-9" class="select">Shipping method(s):</label>
    <select name="select-choice-9" id="select-choice-9" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
        <option>Choose options</option>
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>


</div>
</div>
```

Here is the picture. The gray area is the page size (data-role=page). Since I have a bigger monitor, the menu appears on the extreme right.

[image: Sample Picture]

Comment: show your code? we cannot guess...

Comment: sorry for not clear, edited...

Answer (score 0):

Set the width on the `fieldContain div` instead of the parent `div`

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="width:400px">
    <label for="select-choice-9" class="select">Shipping method(s):</label>
    <select name="select-choice-9" id="select-choice-9" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
        <option>Choose options</option>
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```